# Force fail for $.ajax (deferred)object from php

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am doing a little ajax ping pong and was wondering if it is possible to force a deferred ajax object to fall into fail state from PHP.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'example.com/post',
    dataType: 'json'
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

and in php

```
function post() {
if (false) {
    echo json_encode(array('all good'));
} else {
    ???
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return an error header:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not found');
exit;
```

This will cause jQuery to run its error handler and in turn fail the Ajax deferred. Basically status codes like `4xx` and 5xx` will do the trick.